# LaTeX plugin for IntelliJ IDE (and others from JetBrains)

Tags: editors, ide

Since I'm here for the first time as a registered user, I'll introduce myself. I am a developer that have created a Gitignore plugin last time for [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). It was fun to develop something that others use. After that I was thinking about a new product that I can release and I've checked wishlist on JetBrain's plugins page - there is a request for LaTeX plugin (there are not too much voices in general, but I supose it's because of page's low viewership).

Before I'll start anything I'd like to ask you - does LaTeX plugin for JetBrains' IDEs makes any sense ?

I'd like to hear, what do you think about it - will you use it ? Are there many IntelliJ, etc users ? What would you like to see in initial releases ?

Thanks for the answers and I believe that this non-latex-problem question will not be banished.

Best regards,
hsz

Edit:

As @Joseph Wright pointed me out - not everyone know what IntelliJ is.

IntelliJ is an IDE for programming in Java, PHP, NodeJS, Android, etc.. It allows programmer to write in barely every language that he needs. JetBrains provides [many products](http://www.jetbrains.com/products.html) adapted for various environments (Python/Perl, C#, iOS, Ruby, databases...). As soon as LaTeX is (sorry for that!) just a minor tool in programming, they didn't provide anything to cover it. That's why I got this idea - I am a programmer that needs to write documments in TeX - should I install external software that does not provide version controlling or should I try to create something integrated with powerful IDE that will give me more options, not just writing TeX documents..

I do not know if there are many programmers here and whet do you do in your work, what IDE do you use, but I give a shoot.

**Edit 16.01.2014**

I've started development some time ago. Now it supports syntax coloring (BNF and JFlex rules created).

The source code is available on my GitHub:
https://github.com/hsz/idea-latex

IntelliJ plugin for LaTeX support will be released soon. Keep it in your minds that it'll be very simple version for now.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I wonder if you could provide a bit more info on what the IntelliJ IDE is: I've never heard of it before, and a quick search suggests it's a Java editor, so I'm slightly struggling with where the LaTeX angle is!

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks ! I've edited my answer - I hope it will clarify the problem much better.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense and it's in the wishlist at the fist place in the jetbrains' plugins wishlist http://plugins.jetbrains.com/wishlist?cid=25

Comment: I would love it. And as the wishlist suggests, others would too.

Comment: Please do very appreciated thou it would be a lot of work I guess. Really most editors and the eclipse plugin are just lacking either in features or in ease of use. Im using your gitignore plugin so thx for that too :)

Comment: I think this would be a great addition to IntelliJ. I have been using LaTeX intermittently for over a couple of years now, but I find myself switching editors often as I'm not convinced by any. I'm currently using TeXShop, but often prefer to edit the actual files with vim. For anyone like me that is already used to the shortcuts and key bindings of IntelliJ or other JetBrains products, what would be great in an initial release could be simply a good text editor, with proper syntax highlighting and perhaps an easy way to ensure that whatever packages you are using are actually installed. If yo

Comment: Texshop is for MacOS only

Comment: https://www.texpad.com

Answer (score 6):

I'm a math/computer science teacher in "high school", I'd love a latex plugin for IntelliJ because I use it (a bit) and I also use PyCharm (a lot) and I really like the workflow.
I'm also a LaTeX enthusiast and feel that my current LaTeX editor is a bit "narrow".

Answer (score 2):

hsz, I am a developer too and I constantly need to generate some reports or power point slides for my course work or instructions.

I was using Sublime to edit my latex programs under Windows by setting up the tex compiler location. Sublime supports the syntax highlighting quit well. For linux, I just compile them from command line.

I also use Intellij Idea for some programing tasks, if I can edit and compile latex script under Intellij i IDE, that would be awesome and convenient!

Thank you for starting the project!

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently teaching (inventing) a one semester course in programming (and software tools) for math majors (python, mathematica or maple or matlab, LaTeX, ...). My students are using pycharm. I write LaTeX class notes, using the `listings` package for code (I should probably graduate to `pythontex`). I would be delighted to see a TeX plugin for pycharm.

For the curious, you can follow my course at http://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/480/.