# Latex and IntelliJ Idea

Tags: ide, software

An innocuous question. Is there a way to combine Latex and IntelliJ Idea 15.2

I am astonished by realization on this as it was shown in this [image: picture]

Comment: What do you mean by “combine”?

Comment: See [LaTeX plugin for IntelliJ IDE (and others from JetBrains)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/195670)